# JAXB namespace unmarshal changes between Java 8u45 and 8u111

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have looked through the jaxb and java changelogs between these two versions and have come up empty handed.

In 8u45 this code works fine,

package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.example.org",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED  
) package com.rezometry.fw.net.soap;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

Foo.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class Foo {
    @XmlElement( name = "bar", required = true )
    public String bar;
}
```

Test.java

```
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
import java.io.StringReader;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
@Test public void testJaxB(){
    Foo sample = JAXB.unmarshal( new StreamSource( new StringReader( "<foo><bar>bar1</bar></foo>" ) ), Foo.class );
    assertThat( sample.bar, is("bar1") );
}
```

Yet in 8u111 sample.bar is null.  I have read the various other answers regarding missing namespaces in the xml document, but I want to make sure going forward I am not patching over a bug that might be changed later.

Im am seeing this happen in intellij and the only difference in the set up is what version of java I am using. All other libraries are identical.